# Creating a list of coordinates

Tags: python, coordinates

Let's say my max image size is

```
totalpixels = (45, 45)
```

I want to split this image by

```
split_image = (10,20) #split the 45x45 pixels into 10x20 pixels
```

The resulting list of coordinates which I can have is when I split my 45x45 image into 10x20 is

```
[(0,0), (10,0), (20,0), (30,0), (0,20), (10,20), (20,20), (30,20)]
```

Thus, I start off with (0,0) coordinate and from here I add

```
(0,0)
(10,0)    = (10,0)
(10+10,0) = (20,0)
(20+10,0) = (30,0)
(0,0+20)  = (0,20)    
(0+10,20) = (10,20)
(10+10,20)= (20,20)
(20+10,20)= (30,20)
```

I'm assuming I have to make two for loops,

```
for x in range(total[0]): #Is the range supposed to be this?
    for y in range(total[1]):
         #I'm not sure how to append values according to the split value
```

Comment: What do you mean `split value`? I don't understand the question.

Comment: Can you explain the question properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for` loops are not necessary:

```
>>> [(x, y) for x in range(0, 31, 10) for y in range(0, 21, 20)]
[(0, 0), (0, 20), (10, 0), (10, 20), (20, 0), (20, 20), (30, 0), (30, 20)]
```

This list comprehension produces the result that you specified.

The arguments of range are start, stop, and step. You specified step values of 10 for x and 20 for y.  Note that `range` stops *before* the "stop" value (its 2nd argument).  Consequently, if you want the highest "x" value to be 30, you need to make "stop" just larger than that.

You appear to want the coordinates of the edge of all the pixel blocks of size split_image, starting with (0, 0), that fit within, *but do not extend beyond*, the image of size totalpixels.  A general function to compute this is:

```
def coords(split_image, totalpixels):
    xstop = totalpixels[0] - split_image[0]
    ystop = totalpixels[1] - split_image[1]
    return [(x, y) for x in range(0, xstop, split_image[0])
            for y in range(0, ystop, split_image[1])]
```

When run on your parameter values, it produces:

```
>>> coords( (10, 20), (45, 45) )
[(0, 0), (0, 20), (10, 0), (10, 20), (20, 0), (20, 20), (30, 0), (30, 20)]
```

Comment: John1024's solution is more pythonic than explicit for loops. Another way is `zip(range(0, 31, 10), range(0, 21, 20))`, which also return the list of coordinates. Use xrange and itertools.izip if you have a significant number of tile coordinates you don't want to store in memory at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use range with steps argument:

```
range(start, stop[, step])
```

So you could do it like this:

```
>>> result = []
>>> totalpixels = (45, 45) 
>>> split_image = (10,20) #split the 45x45 pixels into 10x20 pixels
>>> for x in range(0, totalpixels[0], split_image[0]):
...     for y in range(0, totalpixels[1], split_image[1]):
...             result.append((x,y))
... 
>>> result
[(0, 0), (0, 20), (0, 40), (10, 0), (10, 20), (10, 40), (20, 0), (20, 20), (20, 40), (30, 0), (30, 20), (30, 40), (40, 0), (40, 20), (40, 40)]
>>>
```

Or simply

```
>>> [(x, y) for x in range(0, totalpixels[0], split_image[0]) for y in range(0, totalpixels[1], split_image[1])]
[(0, 0), (0, 20), (0, 40), (10, 0), (10, 20), (10, 40), (20, 0), (20, 20), (20, 40), (30, 0), (30, 20), (30, 40), (40, 0), (40, 20), (40, 40)]
```

This would generate the coordinates to split an image like this:

```
   0    10     20   30     40 45
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+--+
   |     |     |     |     |  |
   |     |     |     |     |  |
20 +-----+-----+-----+-----+--+
   |     |     |     |     |  |
   |     |     |     |     |  |
40 +-----+-----+-----+-----+--+
   |     |     |     |     |  |
45 +-----+-----+-----+-----+--+
```

Hope I could help.